# Integrating a Bessel Function $K_0(ax)$ without the constant 'a'.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

Thanks for reading !

I am having a problem with the numerical integration of the Bessel function

$$y = K_0(ax)$$

Since my constant is too large ($a = 6800$) I am getting the large arguments approximation for the Bessel K0 function, making the integration difficult.

My question is: Is there some mathematical method or manipulation to remove the constant 'a' from the integration like

$$y = K_0(x)$$

to make me integrate it like small arguments and then insert the constant 'a' in it somehow after ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Use limit behaviour for this Bessel function
$$K_n(x)\sim \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the response and edit on the question, but I am trying to avoid the use of the large argument expansion because of the various finite part integrals that appear. I am programing a fortran software that uses numeric integration to do the integral, if the argument is small I can integrate it because the singularity is weak, but if the argument is large and there are finite part integrals.

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't help, also there is limit case for $x\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact task that you want to solve?

The obviuos way is to change the variable $u=ax$. There is even a closed form 
$$\int K_0(ax) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{a x K_0(a x) + \frac {1}{2} \pi a x \mathbf{L}_1(ax)
K_0(ax) + \mathbf{L}_0(ax)K_1(ax)}{a}$$
with the modified [Struve functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) $\mathbf{L}_n$. For more info about the $\mathbf{L}_n$ (e.g. asymptotic expansions) see https://dlmf.nist.gov/11 .

The first two high order terms for $a\to \infty$ are
$$\frac{1}{2a}\left(\pi + \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{ax}} e^{-ax}\right)$$

Comment: The  function is:

NIntegrate[(Sqrt[(0. + 0.0078125*(1 - xi) + 
        0.0078125*xi)^2]*(-0.015625 + 0.0078125*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 
      0.0078125*xi*(1 + xi))*
       BesselK[0, 
     6283.185307179586*
      Sqrt[0. + (-0.015625 + 0.0078125*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 
           0.0078125*xi*(1 + xi))^2]])/
    (0. + (-0.015625 + 0.0078125*(1 - xi)*(1 + xi) + 
       0.0078125*xi*(1 + xi))^2), {xi, -1, 1}]

The constant '6283.18' . If it is small, I can integrate it since it has a LOG singularity. If it is large, I cant integrate it since it is large argument with finite part integral

Comment: Is there any mathematical method ( change of variables ?, substitution ? ) that can make me remove this 'a' '6283.185307179586' from the integral ? or make the argument small ? Thank you all for the responses

Comment: It is difficult to decipher your integrand, but it is rather different from your question. Using copy/paste and trial/error with Maple it looks like (with constants $c,b_0,b_1,b_2, c_0, c_1, c_2 $)
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{c K_0\left(a\sqrt{b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2}\right)}{ c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
I would be very surprised it there is a closed form antiderivative for this.
I do not use Mathematica often, so the only hint is, that you may have more 
success if all your constants are converted to  rationals. And you should consider to post this on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Looks like your constant is $a=2000\pi$